# E (6225) cam_hal: FB-SIZE: 230400 != 960000

Tags: camera, esp32

hey iam trying to obtain yuv422 format pictures with framsize of HVGA(640x240) but iam unable to get and iam getting some errors during runtime i configured y camera with below settings

```
 //Camera configuration
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 24000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_YUV422;
  if (psramFound())
  {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_HVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 20;
    config.fb_count = 1;
    config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY;
    config.fb_location  = CAMERA_FB_IN_PSRAM;
  }
  else
  {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }
```

And iam getting below errors

```
E (4558) cam_hal: FB-SIZE: 230400 != 960000
E (5392) cam_hal: FB-SIZE: 230400 != 960000
E (6225) cam_hal: FB-SIZE: 230400 != 960000
```